# How to calculate distance matrix using gDistance in R?

Tags: r, gis

I'd like to calculate distance from polygons. for calculate methode, i use hausdorff distance. i have calculate for 2 polygon only. how to calculate for polygons? need your help please.
this source code for calculate 2 polygon

> library(maptools)
>
> library(rgdal)
>
> shape <- readShapePoly("clipjawa.shp") #load for file .shp
>
> pemalang <- shape[1,1]  #save coordinates from polygon 1 to variable pemalang
>
> tegal <- shape[2,1]  #save coordinates from polygon 2 to variable tegal
>
> distance <- gDistance(pemalang,tegal,hausdorff=TRUE)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to approach this, but perhaps the simplest is to identify all combinations (pairs) of indices of polygons, and apply `gDistance` to each of these combinations.

Here's an example, calculating Hausdorff distances for all pairs of countries in Africa, using the `wrdl_simpl` dataset included with `maptools`.

```
# Load and project the data
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
africa <- spTransform(subset(wrld_simpl, REGION==2), 
                      CRS('+proj=eqc +lon_0=20.390625'))

# Calculate all pairs of polygons
combns <- t(combn(length(africa), 2))

# Split the SPDF into a list of SPDFs
africa.split <- split(africa, seq_len(length(africa)))

# For each row of combns, calculate Haus. dist. for the relevant pair of 
#  polygons
dists <- apply(combns, 1, function(x) 
  gDistance(africa.split[[x[1]]], africa.split[[x[2]]], hausdorff=TRUE))
```

You can then bind these results to the matrix of combinations for convenience:

```
hdists <- cbind.data.frame(from=as.character(africa$NAME[combns[, 1]]), 
                           to=as.character(africa$NAME[combns[, 2]]), 
                           d=dists)

head(hdists)

#      from                               to       d
# 1 Algeria                           Angola 4733071
# 2 Algeria                            Benin 2807129
# 3 Algeria                            Congo 4056594
# 4 Algeria Democratic Republic of the Congo 4532625
# 5 Algeria                          Burundi 5464898
# 6 Algeria                         Cameroon 3071739
```

An alternative approach is to use `outer`, but this should be less efficient since it calculates all distances twice (but it does directly return a distance matrix, which might be desirable).

```
outer(africa.split, africa.split, FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y)  
  gDistance(x, y, hausdorff=TRUE)))
```

(**Updated with an example**)

Comment: I used data from .shp, is that same with data from maptools?

Comment: Most likely (i.e. it's a polygon shapefile with an attribute table). I just used the `wrld_simpl` dataset because it's readily available in R and therefore easily reproducible. Why don't you try it with your data, and comment again if it's not working.

Comment: i got some error on this code line :
hdists <- cbind.data.frame(from=as.character(africa$NAME[combns[, 1]]), 
                           to=as.character(africa$NAME[combns[, 2]]), 
                           d=dists)

the warning is :
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 21

i used 7 data, which makes 21 combns,
can you help me whats going on?

Comment: I assume you mean when you substitute your own data for the Africa example, right? What is `dim(combns)` and `length(dists)`?